# carry flag on MUL overflow bigger than 2^128?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, carryflag

if the following code results in something bigger than 2^128 will it produce a carry (out)?

```
mov rdx, -1 //rdx = 0xff...f
mov rax, -1 //rax = 0xff...f
mov rbx, -1 //rbx = 0xff...f
mul rbx     //result will be bigger than 128 bits therefore will be pushed out of rdx
jc end
...
end: ret
```

So my question boils down to how the carry flag behaves when using the combined registers rax:rdx for `mul`operations. Will `jc` look automatically soley at the rdx register or also trigger when the result is bigger than rax?

Comment: How can the result be bigger than 128 bits?

Comment: @RaymondChen when edx = 1... and rdx:rax is multiplied by two e.g. this should be equal to something like "shl rax:rdx, 2" and therefore be bigger than the two combined registers -> bigger than 128 bits

Comment: `mul rbx` does not multiply `rax:rdx` by `rbx`. It multiplies `rax` by `rbx`. `rdx` is ignored.

Comment: @RaymondChen Im used to x32 assembly. There the mul operation stores the result in `eax:edx` as a combined 64 bit register. Is this behaviour not the same in x64 assembly?

Comment: @RaymondChen says it in the documentation as well... : `MUL r/m64 M Valid N.E. Unsigned multiply (RDX:RAX ← RAX ∗ r/m64).`

Comment: Even in x86-32, `mul ebx` multiplies `eax` by `ebx`. The original value of `edx` is not used. The documentation confirms that `rdx` is not an input: `RDX:RAX ← RAX ∗ r/m64`. This multiplies 64-bit `rax` and 64-bit `r/m64` and puts the 128-bit result into `rdx:rax`.

Comment: When you ran `mov ecx,2` / `mul ecx` (in any mode) with EDX:EAX initially equal to 0xFFFFFFFF:0xFFFFFFFF, what did you see in a debugger?  It didn't match `shld edx, eax, 1` / `shl eax`, did it.  Now go re-read the part of the Intel manual you quoted with fresh eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer Intel's Manual please... https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul#flags-affected
MUL clears the CF if the upper half of the result (RDX, EDX, DX, or AH) is zero, else it's set.

`mul` has two inputs of the same width.  Only the output is double-width.

CF is not used to measure overflow of the whole thing, as two 64 bit multiplicands cannot result into a 129 bit result, so an overflow in that sense is not possible.

**CF actually indicates overflow of the low half**.  Original 8086 didn't have non-widening multiply (`imul ecx, esi`), so you had to use `mul` or `imul` even if you didn't care about the high-half result.  Knowing that the result still fit in one register was potentially useful, especially in a 16-bit world where values wider than the widest available register were more common than on x86-64.